# How to build a library that can be used by both Java and Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, maven, gradle

I am writing the code of the Java server and the Android application at the same time. I found that some eneity codes of the sql database are shared. I hope to extract them and publish them to the local warehouse for the simultaneous use of the two projects.

### Use Maven

I used `android-maven-plugin` maven plugin to import `androidx-room` library, and publish to the maven local warehouse, but I forgot to set KSP.

then Android project report error:

```
[ksp] [MissingType]: Element 'com.sage.feature.article.database.entity.ArticleItemEntity' references a type that is not present - com.sage.feature.article.database.entity.ArticleItemEntity
```

But I checked the information on the Internet, it seems that Maven does not support KSP.

### Use Gradle

Then I try to build with gradle.

I used the following gradle plugins:

```ini
org.springframework.boot
io.spring.dependency-management
org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm
org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Execution failed for task ':core:database:compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:database:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :core:database
      > No matching variant of androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but:
          - Variant 'releaseVariantReleaseApiPublication' capability androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0 declares a library for use during compile-time, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, with the library elements 'aar' and the consumer needed a component, preferably in the form of class files
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
          - Variant 'releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication' capability androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0 declares a library for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, with the library elements 'aar' and the consumer needed a component, preferably in the form of class files
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 17)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'jvm')
```

I guess this is because the gradle plugin that introduces `aar` is not properly configured?

But I can't find more material on the web about gradle kotlin project importing `aar`.

### question

What should I do to build this generic library via `Maven` or `Gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a compatibility issue with gradle jdk v 17

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).